# What's the difference between these sentences?

Tags: differences, british-english, sentence

What's the difference between

> I'm going to eat my lunch

and

> I have to go for my lunch

and where can I use these sentences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first sentence says that you are about to eat your lunch; it may or may not imply that you are leaving the present location to do so, depending on the context.

The second says that it is time for you to eat lunch and that you will be leaving the present location to do so. You would say this when leaving the office to go to the canteen or deli, for example. 'I have to' implies that it is necessary for you to do so, perhaps because you have a set lunch hour.

Comment: I don't think the first construction implies that you are leaving the present location. If you simply said "I'm going to eat lunch," no destination is implied. It is functionally no different from saying "I will eat lunch now." Most Americans, at least, would expect more information before they would expect you were going out, such as "I'm going out to eat lunch."

Comment: @Robusto: 9 times out of 10 I would agree with your reading, but it *could* also be read as "I am going (leaving), in order to eat lunch." I was just covering all the bases.